# Is it possible to divide records processed in Flows in multiple batches

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a flow that creates Opportunity records, we receive CPU time limit if we have too many records. The flow is already bulkified.

The solution I'm thinking is placing a pause logic based on certain conditions.
Will it work or it will wait for the entire loop to process and do DML operation together.

Comment: please see [ask]. CPU time exceeded is a whole-of-transaction limit and flow may only be a part of the entire chain

Comment: There is a way I use sometimes that involves a loop and screens. The screen resets the limits. But you have to sit there and hit "next" on the screen a bunch of times